# Algorithm to queue objects in a step wise manner in a matrix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm

I have an empty object array called `groups`.

Which is initialised as:

```
const groups = [[],[],[]]
```

Now array objects will populate inside each of the arrays inside the root object in the following manner:

The first object will go into the first array, the second object will be paired with the first object in the first array,
the third object will go into the second and the fourth will be paired with the third object in the second array.
Once all the arrays have 2 objects, the next incoming object will go into the first array and then the second, and so on.
Once all the arrays have 3 objects, next incoming object will go into the first array and then the second, and so on.

I have tried `if else`, but I think this has a particular algorithm solution that I cannot figure out.

It would be great if you can point me to the right direction.

*Further clarification*

I tested the logic given below, while it is close to what I am looking for, but in my case there has to be a predefined set of `[[],[],[],[],[]]` 5 arrays inside a root array and each array cannot hold more than 5 objects maximum. And considering your example of using a numerical value as an object it would be something like this if the total number of objects are less than 10: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]` if more than 10 and less than 15: `[[1,2,11],[3,4,12],[5,6,13],[7,8,14],[9,10,15]]`, if more than 15 less than 20: `[[1,2,11,16],[3,4,12,17],[5,6,13,18]...]` and so on.

Comment: The question starts with a statement that is invalid JavaScript. `{[],[],[]}` is invalid. Did you mean `[[],[],[]]`? Or something else?

Comment: What when all three arrays have four elements and another element is added? Where will it go?

Comment: Yes. That was indeed an `[[],[],[]]`. I have edited the question.

Comment: I am a bit disappointed with the update: the consistent logic I had hoped to see is not there. The two first layers follow a different logic than all other layers. It loses beauty. Now it becomes quite trivial. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic seems to first fill the sub arrays with 2 objects each, and then each next object is added in a round-robin order.

We could leave the initialisation of `groups` to be either an array of 3 sub arrays, or 5 sub arrays, or still some other number of sub arrays, and build it up from there.

This leads to the following logic:

```js
let groups = [[], [], [], [], []];

let max = groups.length * groups.length;
let firstPhase = groups.length * 2;
for (let val = 0; val < max; val++) {
   let index = val < firstPhase ? val >> 1 : val % groups.length;
   groups[index].push(val+1); // +1 because you start numbering from 1.
   console.log(JSON.stringify(groups));
}
```

Comment: I tested the logic, while it is close to what I am looking for, but in my case there has to be a predefined set of `[[],[],[],[],[]]` 5 arrays inside a root array and each array cannot hold more than 5 objects maximum. And considering your example of using a numerical value as an object it would be something like this if the total number of objects are less than 10: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]` if more than 10 and less than 15: `[[1,2,11],[3,4,12],[5,6,13],[7,8,14],[9,10,15]]`, if more than 15 less than 20: `[[1,2,11,16],[3,4,12,17],[5,6,13,18]...]` and so on.

Comment: I have further edited my original question.

Comment: This is a correct solution to the problem with a minor tweaking that I did. In the final solution it is a random (not fixed length) set of predefined empty arrays, and until all the empty arrays get filled in the first phase with two digits (objects) in each array while maintaining the order, I cannot proceed to the next phase of appending the remaining objects to the array. Sorry for disappointing you.

Comment: Don't know why this question was closed as offtopic, Algorithm questions are not allowed?

Comment: Don't ask me. I didn't close it, and I also don't understand why it was.

Comment: I don't know where to appeal to get this question open, when they closed it they left the following statement: "Not suitable for this site".

Comment: It does not matter. I think you got your answer, and this Q&A will still show up on internet searches. If however you have a another/follow-up question, then just ask a new question, making sure you provide the necessary information, examples, expected output, etc.